# How to make sweetalert works for your button

Tags: javascript, sweetalert

[Here](http://www.ilcontadinobio.it/tests/index.html) my small mail sender.

I liked how sweetalert work, so I decided to go for it.
[Here](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) is where I took the infos.

I downloaded everything necessary. Made the due calls as they suggest.
I believe everything should be okay so far, even if they made one call on their source code different than those suggested.
Where I believe my problem lies is on the js code snippet they advise to use. Well, actually the just wrote "Call the sweetAlert-function after the page has loaded" so I assumed it should be some code between `<script></script>` tags. At fist glance it seems a too simple piece of code.

`<script>document.querySelector('ul.examples li.success button').onclick = function(){swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success");};</script>` is what they use to make the alert I am interested in works in their page's source code.

Where am I doing wrong?
Anyone willing to help?
Thank you :)

Comment: There’s a missing `}` at the end. Also, please choose a title that is more descriptive of your problem.

Comment: It seems as though your page is not loading the javascript for SweetAlert.  You should be able to test this just by trying to invoke SweetAlert from the javascript console.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance but where can I find the javascript console?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your page is loading the javascript and css that are required for SweetAlert.

A simple functional snippet, using SweetAlert assets from a CDN is posted here.

```js
swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.0.1/sweetalert.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.0.1/sweetalert.min.css">
```

Comment: I made sure my page is loading the javascript and css that are required for SweetAlert and I added <script>swal("Good job!", "You clicked the button!", "success");</script> in the head of my page. I'm not getting any alert when I submit.

Comment: Using your live page I can now invoke SweetAlert from the javascript console, so it is loading correctly but a javsacript error is thrown when the page renders that indicates a problem trying to invoke SweetAlert at that point.  The following describes a bug in SweetAlert which may be what you are seeing: https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert/issues/78

Comment: Thanks, it is working now but other than on click the alert appears every time the page gets loaded.

Comment: If you don't want the alert `onload` then remove the call to SweetAlert that has no condition (I think that was only added for testing).  If you mark my answer as accepted then you will be awarded +2 rep points.

Comment: Sorry but I lost you. Not really sure what are you referring to when talking about "call to SweetAlert that has no condition".

As for the working code snippet, this is what I used: `<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
       swal("Thank you!", "Your address has been successfully submitted!", "success");
    }, 1000);
});
</script>`The one suggested in your helpful link.
Perhaps the problem lies within it.

Comment: I do not believe so. The alert doesn't appear straight after the button click. It appears after the page has been loaded. You can check it by yourself http://www.ilcontadinobio.it/tests/index.html